# How to configure Alfresco 6 Community behind proxy?

Tags: alfresco, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to use the settings from this docker-compose: https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-deployment/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml

It works only if I don't change the host/port/protocol (scheme).

Alfresco still redirect my login page to port 8080 even if I set:

- `-Dshare.host=example.org`
- `-Dshare.port=443`
- `-Dshare.protocol=https`
- `-Dalfresco.host=example.org`
- `-Dalfresco.port=443`
- `-Dalfresco.protocol=https`
- `-Daos.baseUrlOverwrite=https://example.org/alfresco/aos`

My infrastructure:

```
  haproxy (provide SSL :443) 
  -> Alfresco's NGiNX Proxy (:8080) 
     -> Alfresco Share (:8080) 
        -> Alfresco Content Services (:8080)
```

- Alfresco Components: https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.0/install/containers/docker-compose/#deployment-project-in-github
- NGiNX config: https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-ingress/blob/master/nginx.conf

Comment: What happens if you set the share.host to the IP address of the haproxy?

Comment: are you sure you pass the required proxy headers from haproxy (similar to the lines in [nginx](https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-ingress/blob/83b0337743801a7b323caeda3f242266c611c781/nginx.conf#L23)?

Answer (score 0):

Please compare the values of the config files with your configuration's.

**CORS Portion in web.xml**

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
         <param-value>*</param-value>
         <!--param-value>http://localhost:8081,https://localhost:3000,https://dms.sws-digital.com</param-value-->
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
         <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
         <param-value>origin, authorization, x-file-size, x-file-name, content-type, accept, x-file-type</param-valu$      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
         <param-value>3600</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </filter>
[...]
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/s/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/cmisbrowser/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Configurations of alfresco dockers (ngnix https proxy)**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
[...]
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/sws-digital.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/sws-digital.com.key;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;

        root                    /var/www/html;

        server_name             dms.sws-digital.com;

        rewrite                 ^/$     /share;

        location /share {
                proxy_pass              http://share:8080;
                #proxy_redirect         off;

                proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;

                proxy_set_header        Origin                  "";
                proxy_set_header        Proxy                   "";
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Frowarded-Proto       $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        Referer                 "";

                # Allow large file upload
                client_max_body_size    0;

        }

        location /alfresco {
                proxy_pass              http://alfresco:8080;
                #proxy_redirect         off;

                proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
                proxy_set_header        Proxy                   "";
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_set_header       X-Frowarded-Proto       $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        Referer                 "";

                # large files upload
                client_max_body_size    0;
        }
```

**Config in alfresco-global.properties:**

```
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=dms.sws-digital.com
alfresco.port=443
alfresco.protocol=https
share.context=share
share.host=dms.sws-digital.com
share.port=443
share.protocol=https
opencmis.context.override=false
opencmis.context.value=
opencmis.servletpath.override=false
opencmis.servletpath.value=
opencmis.server.override=true
opencmis.server.value=https://dms.sws-digital.com
aos.baseUrlOverwrite=https://dms.sws-digital.com/alfresco/aos
```

Also you can give a try with the new docker [installer](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-docker-installer),

This project will produce a Docker Compose template with HA Proxy using NGINX.